# Is it possible to load Google Remarketing Tag using flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, adobe, google-ads-api

I would like to load up an AdWords remarketing tag on my website that has very little CMS to it. I currently cannot login or edit the website in any way as I am locked out of the FTP for the next weeks until I sort out payment to a developer who hosts it for me.

I can however upload flash files to my website that I normally use to let people advertise on my site. Is there a possibility to embed the Javascript code from Google into the Flash file and upload it, and then track all users to the site with the Javascript Remarketing Code?

So in short:

Can regular Javascript be run from a standard `.swf` file?
Can the Google Remarketing Tag be run from a standard `.swf` file?